# Can I change class component into functional component? - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I use class component. Just testing it. Now I don't know how to convert it into functional. This is my code:

```
class PostList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          info: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { info } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>post!</h2>
        {info.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.symbol}>
            <h6>{user.priceChange}</h6>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostList;
```

*I should use this code in my redux and I need to convert it into functional component*

*I want something like this:*

````
export const PostList = () =>{
   return (
    //my code using axios,       
   )
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functional component, you should use `hooks` instead of classify components default `state` and `componentDidMount`. So for define a new state you need to use `useState` and for `componentDidMount` you need to use `useEffect`:

```
const PostList  = (props) => {
   const [state,setState] = useState({info:[]});
   useEffect(()=>{
      axios
      .get("https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr")
      .then((response) => {
        setState({
          info: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      });
     },[])

  const { info } = state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>post!</h2>
        {info.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.symbol}>
            <h6>{user.priceChange}</h6>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}


export default PostList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use functional components, you will have to use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)!

In your case, using the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks can help to achieve the same result as `this.state` and `componentDidMount()` respectively.

```js
const PostList  = (props) => {
   const [state,setState] = useState({info:[]});
   
   useEffect(()=>{
      axios
      .get("https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr")
      .then((response) => {
        setState({
          info: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      });
     },[])

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>post!</h2>
        {state.info.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.symbol}>
            <h6>{user.priceChange}</h6>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}


export default PostList;
```

Comment: Could you please describe what's the difference between this answer and the answer which is given?

Comment: Sorry, i just noticed that there was answer that is similar. However, I believe the difference is in the line `const { info } = this.state;`. Correct me if I'm wrong but since it is now a functional component, we can no longer have to use the `this` keyword. Additionally, we can also just do a `state.info.map` to reference the info property in the state